# Python - Convert ISO 8601 to BST time

Tags: python, datetime, time

So basically I have learned a bit with ISO 8601 where the format is

```
"2018-07-06T07:00:00.000"
```

and basically what I have achieved is that I starting of to change the ISO to a more formal timestamp which is:

```
etatime = str(datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-07-06T07:00:00.000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

which will give an output of:

```
2018-07-06 07:00:00
```

However I noticed the time is 1 hour behind the BST (British time) which should be added one hour.

My question is, is there possible to go from (`2018-07-06T07:00:00.000`) to  (`2018-07-06 08:00:00 BST`)?

Comment: So that original timestamp represents the time *in UTC*? Since there's no timezone information included, "going to BST" is an undefined operation.

Comment: Oh, actually I dont know the represents time it is actually,  because UTC is usually the same time as BST - which is uncorrect for my question. I think it is just faulty made or something like that, all I know is that it is 1 hour behind the BST, which I can't really tell what timezone it is who has 1 hour behind BST - I assume GMT-1 in that case.

Comment: So, that's what you need to figure out. "One hour off" could mean that the date has been generated wrong and is truly *one hour off*; it could mean that it represents UTC and you want to localise it to BST; it could mean it has been generated in some other local timezone and you want to localise it to BST… The correct thing to do depends on which of these assumptions is true.

Comment: Oh you are totally correct, I just mindblowed myself. It is UTC time and BST is UTC + 1 basically. So you are absolutely correct when you meant that it is time for *UTC*. So yes. Converting from UTC to BST would be my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions: the input represents a UTC timestamp, and you want to localise that to *London* time. You probably do not want to localise it to BST time, since BST is the DST variation of GMT, and an actual location like London will switch between BST and GMT depending on the time of year. You'll want to install the [`pytz` module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz

date = '2018-07-06T07:00:00.000'
utc_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
london_date = utc_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
```

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' BST+1:00:00 DST>)
```

`strptime` gives you a *naïve* `datetime` object (without timezone information), `.replace` gives you an *aware* `datetime` object (with timezone information), which then enables you to simply convert that to a different timezone.

Comment: Looks liek it working, However I can't get the step where I can remove the end of the print - The print right now looks `2018-07-05 08:00:00+01:00` and basically I just want to remove the last `+01:00`, is that possible to do?

Comment: You want to explicitly format your timestamp: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

Comment: I was looking at it, but I hav eno idea how I can replace/remove the timezone information at the end since there is none in the documentatiuon that I can find :/

Comment: It's not about "removing" anything, it's about outputting the date in a format you like, in this case without mentioning the timezone anywhere: `london_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`.

Comment: Oh but why do we need to `strfttime` twice, isnt it enough already in utc_date that you can directly make the changes from there?

Comment: Nope, not twice. `strptime` (P!) *parses* a string into a `datetime` object. `strftime` (F!) *formats* a `datetime` object to a string according to your desired format.

Comment: Ohhh! Of course I missed the F and P! That makes sense now! Apprecaite it. I need to read more about pytz do actually know whats the difference between that and the normal time, does it automatic convert during the summer/winter time aswell? If you have that on your mind,.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is that you can use the `timedelta` function from `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

etatime = datetime.strptime("2018-07-06T07:00:00.000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

# Before adding one hour
print(etatime)

etatime = etatime + timedelta(hours=1)

# After adding one hour
print(etatime)
```

Output:

```
2018-07-06 07:00:00
2018-07-06 08:00:00
```

Comment: Hmm im getting an issue saying: `module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: Oh, I by accident had an str left. My bad!